# (Python) socket.gaierror on every addres...except http://www.reddit.com?

Tags: python, http, sockets

I'm just playing around and I'm trying to grab information from websites. Unfortunately, with the following code:

```
import sys
import socket
import re
from urlparse import urlsplit

url = urlsplit(sys.argv[1])


sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((url[0] + '://' + url[1],80))
path = url[2]
if not path:
    path = '/'

print path
sock.send('GET ' + path + ' HTTP/1.1\r\n'
    + 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.3.154.9 Safari/525.19\r\n'
    + 'Accept: */*\r\n'
    + 'Accept-Language: en-US,en\r\n'
    + 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,*,utf-8\r\n'
    + 'Host: 68.33.143.182\r\n'
    + 'Connection: Keep-alive\r\n'
    + '\r\n')
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "D:\Development\Python\PyCrawler\PyCrawler.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       sock.connect((url[0] + '://' + url[1],80))   File "", line 1,
>   in connect socket.gaierror: (11001,
>   'getaddrinfo failed')

The only time I do not get an error is if the url passed is http://www.reddit.com. Every other url I have tried comes up with the socket.gaierror. Can anyone explain this? And possibly give a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please please please please please please please don't do this.

urllib and urllib2 are your friends.

Read [the "missing" urllib2 manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) if you are having trouble with it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> sock.connect((url[0] + '://' + url[1],80))
> ```

Do not do that, instead do this:

```
sock.connect((url[1], 80))
```

`connect` expects a hostname, not a URL.

Actually, you should probably use something higher-level than sockets to do HTTP. Maybe [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

Comment: I've tried that too. It gives me Access Denied errors everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever altered your [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file)? If it has an entry for Reddit but not much else, that might explain that site's  unique result.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to resolve the hostname:

```
addr = socket.gethostbyname(url[1])
...
sock.connect((addr,80))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use urllib2. Or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).