# Catch gaierror in Django / Python?

Tags: python, django

How do I properly catch a gaierror in Django or Python? This error is brought up when a request to a 3rd party API is made and no connection can be made. I tried a `try` with an empty `except` but the gaierror was not caught.

Advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen some rumbling in some websearches about using urllib and urllib2 to catch these errors. Maybe something in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303726/python-socket-gaierror-on-every-addres-except-http-www-reddit-com) may help you.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up catching socket.error to solve this. Don't forget to "import socket" on top!